# SED or other editor - remove strings from file on Windows

Tags: text, sed, grep, editor, findstr

I need to find a string in a textfile, delete the line containing it, and save the file. The string is found (read from) another textfile, containing hundreds of different strings, one per row. The process is to go on from the first to the last string in the file.

Any (hopefully easy to use) text editors (on Windows OS) recommended ? To achive the task.

I am not into serious day-to-day editing. So I'd be ever so happy if the task could be accomplished with a easy-to-use but still reliable editor.

Thanks a bunch,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On unix/linux/cygwin:

`grep -v -f pattern_file unmodified_file > new_file`

Remove all lines containing the patterns in pattern_file from unmodified_file, write to new_file.

`grep -v` outputs lines not matching any pattern. `-f` reads patterns from a file.

On windows this appears equivalent to running this at the command prompt:

`FINDSTR /V /G:pattern_file unmodified_file > new_file`

That's it.  If you already have the two source files, it's a one-liner.

`pattern_file` is going to be whitespace and case sensitive unless you delve into other options, which are described with `FINDSTR /?`

Comment: Hello stevesliva, thanks. I'll try the Windows one and be back, to tell how it worked out.

Comment: Hello again, tried as you suggested and Yahoo! it worked out first hit. Did some checking, so far did not find any glitches in the newly created 'new_file'. I 'knew' there must be a way to do it w Winders, needed to find the right guy w the right advice. Neat & clean. Thanks a lot stevesliva !

Comment: @frank I mention the `grep` implementation mostly because that's canonical to those of us who mangle text with code on a daily basis, but sure enough this did map exactly to a DOS command.   I'd appreciate it if you accept the answer (green checkmark). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try notepad++ since it has a lot of plugins, also a great search algorithm. I did a similar task where I had to do a lot of search/replace stuff, and used a plugin I dug up from the internet, can't remember the name exactly (try google-ing I think it's replaacc for notepad++ or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/PATTERN/n;p' FILE > FILE.new # then copy FILE.new to FILE
```

Tells sed to not output anything by default (`-n`), find the pattern (`/PATTERN/`) and skip this line if found (`n`), otherwise print the line (`;p`). If you have `GNU sed` you do can just call

```
sed -i -n '/PATTERN/n;p' FILE`
```

which automatically updates the file due to (`-i /--in-place`).

Comment: Hello toting, I'am going to try stevesliva's first as it avoids to install a Winders version of SED. But hey, thanks anyway, who knows.